# resize the font size of the text box

Tags: javascript

I am using the below code to shrink the font size, but it will reduce only once, I want it to reduce every time when i enter a new character.

```
<input type="text" value=""  id="allocatedVisionBudget" onkeydown="resizetext()">


 <style>
#allocatedVisionBudget {
    width: 10%;
    height: 93.3px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0);
    border: none;
    font-size: 60px;
    color: #7e8081;
     padding: 0px;
}
</style>

<script>
function resizetext(){

        var xy = document.getElementById('allocatedVisionBudget').value;
        var x = document.getElementById("allocatedVisionBudget").style.fontSize=60;
        //x;
        xy;
        var i=0;
        var y=xy.length;
        if(xy.length > 4) {
             document.getElementById("allocatedVisionBudget").style.fontSize=x-20;
     }
}
</script>
```

Comment: @SrinivasR, javascript, not jquery!

Comment: @SrinivasR No, it's not. `getElementById` only expects an ID, so you don't pass the **hash** identifier.

Comment: oh sorry my bad ..... i removed my ans . thanks @Gavriel and george

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have one condition:

```
if(xy.length > 4) {
```

so it only resizes when you change the lenght from 4 to 5 or from 5 to 4.
Either add more conditions, or better make the fontSize calculated as a function of the text length:

```
document.getElementById("allocatedVisionBudget").style.fontSize=f(xy);
```

```js
function resizetext(e){
     var xy = document.getElementById('allocatedVisionBudget').value;
     var l=xy.length;
     var f = Math.ceil(80/xy.length) || 60;
     console.log(e, xy, l, f);
     document.getElementById("allocatedVisionBudget").style.fontSize=f + "px";
}
```

```css
#allocatedVisionBudget {
    width: 10%;
    height: 93.3px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0);
    border: #f00 solid 1px;
    font-size: 60px;
    color: #7e8081;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
Input: <input type="text" value=""  id="allocatedVisionBudget" onkeypress="resizetext(event)" onkeydown="resizetext(event)" onkeyup="resizetext(event)">
```

Comment: can you upload the code to make the fontSize calculated as a function of the text length

Comment: See my answer now. It works, but it's not perfect. The problem is that when the callback is called onkeydown you don't know yet what will be the text after this event will be applied (in other words, when you see the value is "123" and now you're in a keydown event, you don't know if the text will be shorter/same/longer after the current event will be processed, because the key can be "4" but it can be backspace or delete or just shift as well.

Answer (score 0):

a few things you need to do

1. when you set to input element font size it should wrap as string with px or % etc...

   this is example:

   var x = document.getElementById("allocatedVisionBudget").style.fontSize 
        = "60px";
2. when you use x-20 the x is string so you need to use the parseInt(x) function

here is a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/0gukbLny/) for your code

HTML:

```
<input type="text" value="" id="allocatedVisionBudget" onkeydown="resizetext()">
```

javascript:

```
window.resizetext = function() {

  var xy = document.getElementById('allocatedVisionBudget').value;
  var x = document.getElementById("allocatedVisionBudget").style.fontSize =  "60px";

  var i = 0;
  var y = xy.length;
  if (xy.length > 4) {
    document.getElementById("allocatedVisionBudget").style.fontSize =     (parseInt(x) - 20) + "px";
  }
};
```

CSS:

```
#allocatedVisionBudget {
 width: 100%;
 height: 93.3px;
 background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);  
 font-size: 60px;
 color: #7e8081;
 padding: 0px;
}
```

Comment: it will work only if the length is greater than 4, What i want is every time i enter a character it to decrease the font size, and when delete the character font size to increase as normal